# Android LinearLayout fill more than parent

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingdrawer

Im not getting this layout thingy right.

Here are some pictures to make it easies for me to explain:

[image]

That green thing is the temporary icon to the SlidingDrawer. As you see I want it to get the whole way up to the other gray field, so that the gray backgounds becomes one, and the handler icon overlaps the top field.

This is how the xml looks like now:

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/info_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/drawer_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_ip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_in"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/wifi_unknown"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_mo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:typeface="monospace" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/discover_empty"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

        <!-- Slider -->
        <SlidingDrawer
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:content="@+id/content"
            android:handle="@+id/handle" >

            <!-- Image for the handler to the slider -->
            <ImageView
                android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
                android:id="@id/handle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/drawer_handle" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@id/content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/slider_bg"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <!-- Horisontal layout : wide as possible, but height is minimal -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dip"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <!-- Search button -->
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_discover"
                        style="@style/ButtonTop"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/discover"
                        android:text="@string/btn_discover" />

                    <!-- Option button -->
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_options"
                        style="@style/ButtonTop"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/settings"
                        android:text="@string/btn_options" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- The list with network devices inside the slidingdrawer-->
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/output"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                    android:dividerHeight="0dip" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </SlidingDrawer>
    </FrameLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Ive tried RelativeLayout, but I cant get it right.
Sorry for my bad explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to overlap the info pane with the sliding drawer it too (the info pane layiut) needs to be inside the framelayout.

That simple change should make it work like you want it to.